# Need to mask the First 5 digits and display only last 4 digits of SSN

Tags: custom-field, formula-field

I have a field named SSN__c which is Text. The fields are managed.
I get the Data from External API.
I dont want to display the full SSN on page layouts.
How can i convert the Text to Number and Display only last 4 digits?

Formula field or and other way?

Comment: Personally, I'd set field security to private for that field, create a new field that's Text (Encrypted), then set your integration to point to the new field. Failing that, you could just copy the value directly via workflow rule. Either way, encrypted fields should be your first thought.

Comment: I cant go with Encrypted Field now.
Any other way i can mask in the formula field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Deny Read access to SSN Field using field level security so SSN is secure
2. Create a formula text field Right(SSN_C,4) which should get the last 4 digits and display it in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Shield  Platform Encryption. Configure a Field Encryption Policy.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/spe_admins

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.